# MVC 3 MultiSelectList Posting Values for Complex Types

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, complextype, multi-select

If I have a complex type e.g.

```
public class Customer
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public List<ContactType> ContactTypes {get;set;}
}

public class ContactType
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and my strongly typed view binds the `ContactType` like so ...

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ContactTypes , 
                  new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.ContactTypes, "Id", "Name"))
```

and my action method signature is ...

```
public ActionResult Create(Customer customer){}
```

why is the `customer.ContactTypes` null when I post the form? I can see the posted data
like `ContactTypes=1&ContactTypes=2`, I though this would bind to the `ContactTypes`?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Your model is wrong. You should have a collection property to bind the selected values to. You should not use the same property for the both arguments of your SelectList. So start by adding a property on your view model to hold the selected ids:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<int> SelectedContactTypeIds { get; set; }
    public List<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and then fix your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
    m => m.SelectedContactTypeIds, 
    new MultiSelectList(Model.ContactTypes, "Id", "Name")
)
```

Now inside your `Create` action you will get the `SelectedContactTypeIds` property containing the selected ids:

```
public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
{
    // here the customer.SelectedContactTypeIds will contain the ids of the selected items
    ...
}
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you have bound the SelectList to the `ContactTypes` property which is a complex type and as you know the `<select>` element sends only the selected values when the form is submitted. That's how HTML works.